# Drupal 7 treating HTML div with data attribute as text

Tags: html, drupal-7, skrollr

I'm trying to implement skrollr.js into drupal 7.

When I key in this code:

```
<div data-top="opacity: 1" data--400-top="opacity: 0" class="abc"></div>
```

It treats data as text and print out as:

```
data-top="opacity: 1" data--400-top="opacity: 0" class="abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the raw html block in Drupal and putting your code in there?  I run into a similar problem using Skrollr and WordPress.